# how to get the tweets from the tweeter using tweetstream python

Tags: python-2.7, tweetstream

I have written this script:

```
import tweetstream   
import pymongo  
connection = pymongo.Connection("mongodb://localhost:27017")  
db = connection.socialdata  
words = ["social media", "innovation", "cloud computing"]  
with tweetstream.FilterStream('username', 'password', track=words) as stream:  
    for tweet in stream:         
        db.tweets.save(tweet)
```

But on execution I am getting following error please tell me how to remove this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "tweet.py", line 9, in <module>
        with tweetstream.FilterStream(username, password, track=words) as stream:
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 5 arguments (4 given)</module>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're missing one argument. It expects 5 arguments, and you've given it 4. `tweetstream`, `username`, `password`, and `track`. Read the documentation to see what's the one missing

Comment: I suggest using Twython.

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering how you got `tweetstream` working in the first place because all I know is that basic username/password access was [deprecated](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/18699) some time back. Now Twitter allows OAuth access only.

---

Turning back to your question, your `FileStream` call is perfectly valid. Look at `FileStream` class implementation and you'd understand why.

Following are few lines of code from `FilterStream` class which is available [here](https://bitbucket.org/runeh/tweetstream/src/2b1e2fdeb3c8043cdd7b34dfa8df99561693978b/tweetstream/streamclasses.py?at=default)

```
def __init__(self, username, password, follow=None, locations=None,
                 track=None, catchup=None, raw=False, timeout=None, url=None):
        self._follow = follow
        self._locations = locations
        self._track = track
        # remove follow, locations, track
        BaseStream.__init__(self, username, password,
                            raw=raw, timeout=timeout, url=url)
```

So, `tweetstream.FilterStream("username", "password", track=words)` should work. Because as you can see there are only 3 mandatory arguments for `__init__`. (self,username, password).

All others are optional. Please be noted that this code is from tweetstream 1.1.1 which I think the last version released.

---

However, as said in your error,`FilterStream` constructor in `tweetstream` takes a minimum of 5 arguments.

[This](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tweetstream) documentation gives an example for what you are trying to do.

As it says, try using this initialization instead,

```
with tweetstream.FilterStream("username", "password", track=words,
                               follow=people, locations=locations) as stream
```

According to the source,

- Locations are a list of bounding boxes in which geotagged tweets
  should originate. The argument should be an iterable of
  longitude/latitude pairs.
- Track specifies keywords to track. The argument should be an iterable
  of strings.
- Follow returns statuses that reference given users. Argument should
  be an iterable of twitter user IDs. The IDs are userid ints, not the
  screen names.

Comment: thanks for your reply. But I tried the same given on that link still getting the same error so is there any another way to do this please suggest.

Comment: @ShilpaJawale, what library are you exactly using? Streaming API ?

Comment: I am using tweetstream library

Comment: hi can you tell me the alternative to the tweetstream for doing this task as tweeter api(1.1) does not support tweetstream

Comment: See if [this](http://code.google.com/p/python-twitter/) helps. By the way @ShilpaJawale, isn't the username/password access deprecated by Twitter now? I think now they allow OAuth only